# In XPath how can I check if a list contains a specific item?

Tags: dom, xpath, tokenize

I need to have a list contains function in xpath which will work like this:

```
//*[contains( ("one", "two", "three"), "one")
```

Is there anything like this?

Just for context, this is the problem I am trying to solve:

I have got a DOM tree

```
<element blah="one two three">

<element blah="bone two three">

<element blah="two three one">
```

I want to select the first and third because they cone contain one.

```
//*[contains(tokenize(@blah,'\s+'),'one')]
```

This is what I have so far, but it doesn't seem to be a valid XPath query.

I know that tokenize returns something in this format:

```
("one", "two", "three")
```

What I need is to be able to check what is in that list.

Answer (score 1):

Simple:

```
"one" = ("one", "two", "three")
```

Or the more lengthy:

```
some $i in ("one", "two", "three") satisfies $i eq "one"
```

Comment: .//*[contains(@class,'ibmPortalControl')]//*[contains(concat(' ',@class,' '), ' decoration-title ')]

Is what I needed. By wrapping the 'decoration-title' with spaces on each side it made it easy to find and didn't mean we had to search through a results set.